# Ruby product method behaving differently in case of arrays of strings

Tags: ruby

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Array.html#method-i-product)

```
[1,2].product([3,4],[5,6])
=> [[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

returns an array of all combinations of elements from all arrays.
However,

```
first_array = ["orange", "purple", "colour-black"]
other_arrays = [["sputter", "ribus"], ["incontinentia", "portia"]]
@end_array = first_array.product(other_arrays)
```

returns, unexpectedly:

```
[["orange", ["sputter", "ribus"]], ["orange", ["incontinentia", "portia"]], ["purple", ["sputter", "ribus"]], ["purple", ["incontinentia", "portia"]], ["colour-black", ["sputter", "ribus"]], ["colour-black", ["incontinentia", "portia"]]]
```

why is ruby behaving differently? What could be done to get the designed result ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rb
[1,2].product([3,4],[5,6])
```

This line is passing two arguments to `.product`.

```rb
@end_array = first_array.product(other_arrays)
```

This line is passing a *single* argument to `.product`, which happens to be an array of arrays.  Now does the result make sense?  It's equivalent to:

```rb
[1,2].product([[3,4],[5,6]])
```

You can de-structure the array into separate arguments with the [splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) (`*`):

```rb
first_array = ["orange", "purple", "colour-black"]
other_arrays = [["sputter", "ribus"], ["incontinentia", "portia"]]
@end_array = first_array.product(*other_arrays)

=> [["orange", "sputter", "incontinentia"],
 ["orange", "sputter", "portia"],
 ["orange", "ribus", "incontinentia"],
 ["orange", "ribus", "portia"],
 ["purple", "sputter", "incontinentia"],
 ["purple", "sputter", "portia"],
 ["purple", "ribus", "incontinentia"],
 ["purple", "ribus", "portia"],
 ["colour-black", "sputter", "incontinentia"],
 ["colour-black", "sputter", "portia"],
 ["colour-black", "ribus", "incontinentia"],
 ["colour-black", "ribus", "portia"]]
```

Comment: not supposed to comment in this manner, but the splat operator is nice, compact, elegant.